# Can git retain file owner, permissions, ACLs, and file attributes on a local Windows NTFS machine?

Tags: windows, git, windows-7, permissions, ntfs

If I commit some code on a Windows machine with an NTFS hard drive into git, and then check it back out again in a another directory, will it retain my original Owner, NTFS permissions ACLs, and file attributes?

If so will it automatically break inheritance to do so, or does it require a setting of some sort?

Comment: In and of itself, GIT is a multiplatform tool, and as such necessarily doesn't know anything about anyone's file systems or ACL's. The local file system into which you fetch file(s) is incidental. Suppose you got a file on a Windows box, but then later edited it on a Linux box...the Windows permission info would be meaningless.

Comment: @DavidW So I guess this goes for ACLs in Linux too?

Comment: Surely, because the two are fundamentally dissimilar entities. They may perform similar function in each environment, but a Windows ACL is meaningless to Linux, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GIT is a platform-independent code management tool, and can be run on numerous different operating systems. As a result, it is necessarily indifferent to any particular platform's notions of security or access control information. Security metadata about a file in Windows would be meaningless in, for example, a Linux environment, and vice-versa.

Comment: Not necessarily.  There's nothing actually stopping Git from recording this information and using it if and only if the platform matches.  I assume it doesn't, because it wouldn't make much sense for it to do so, but it could if it wanted to.

Comment: @HarryJohnston This seems like a good answer, can you elaborate and then I'll select it as the answer?

Comment: In that circumstance, however, an ACL would be essentially meaningless outside its originating environment; the SID's incorporated in that ACL that refer to particular users would be meaningless in a wholly different Windows-based network, eg SID from domain X applied to domain Y.

Comment: @leeand00: I recommend that you select this answer.  I'm just nitpicking, David's answer is essentially correct.

Comment: @DavidW: yes, though there are edge cases, such as using Git for an internal project in a domain environment.  You can also construct a universally portable ACL using well-known SIDs only if you know what you're doing.  Fundamentally, though, I just don't see any reason why anyone would *want* the repository to contain ACLs, even if they worked perfectly.